# Show that $dn^{\beta}/(\epsilon n^{1/2})^2$ can be written as $d /(\epsilon^2)(n^{(1-\beta)})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that $dn^{\beta}/(\epsilon n^{1/2})^2$ can be written as $d /(\epsilon^2)(n^{(1-\beta)})$

I have tried $d n^{\beta}/(\epsilon^2) (n^{5/2})$ and then $dn^{(\beta-5/2)}/\epsilon^2$
But the 5/2 is throwing me I don't see how this becomes 1

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your error is the following:

You say that $(n^{1/2})^2=n^{1/2+2}=n^{5/2}$.

This is not true. The true one is $(n^{1/2})^2=n^{\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2}=n^1$.

Comment: Fantastic thank you I was still trying to edit as per the link provided.